# Display bug with voting buttons

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, election

The voting buttons on the election page are cutting off the text, and not by a little.

[image: screen crop]

I am using Google Chrome 32.0.1700.102 m on Windows 7. (It's not happening in Firefox 26.0.)

Comment: Reproducing sometimes, also Windows chrome. Only sometimes, which is weird.

Comment: Repro on iOS as well. (Safari, iPad, ios7 to be specific.) Also only sometimes.

Comment: Occasional repro on Chrome 34, at least on Ubuntu and Chrome OS. I guess it's a browser bug.

Comment: I've had more issues with chrome breaking table layouts before. Since the buttons are in a table, I'm assuming it's related to that. Firefox has no problems at all.

Comment: Repro on Safari 5.1.10/Mac OS 10.6.8. Quitting and reopening the page fixed it for me.

Comment: Happens on all my browsers (up-to-date IE11, Chrome, Opera, Firefox) on Win8.1, but usually it shows up fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old report, and it might've been fixed at some point before... but in case it still persisted, [the new voting UI we rolled out last month](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361979/208518) will have eliminated the issue altogether for sure.

[image: new voting UI with drag-and-drop functionality and mobile responsive view]